# google chrome extensions development

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop my first extension in google chrome and I am following this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension)
Everything is working great except the 2 lines of code in content.js
The problem is that the contents of "content.js" are not correct and I am getting "undefined" in chrome console for line 2. 
Can someone please help me out and let me know why this happens?
I share the contents of content.js with you in order to help me out.

content.js contents:

```
var firstHref = $("a[href^='http']").eq(0).attr("href");
console.log(firstHref);
```

manifest/json file contents:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My Cool Extension",
"version": "0.2",
"icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "js": ["jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "content.js"]
}
],
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"permissions": [
"tabs"
]
}
```

Comment: Did you inject jQuery?

Comment: Yes I did this by adding the jquery-2.1.3.min.js file in my extension folder. I also shared my manifest file above in order to check for yourself.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I have shared all needed information Makyen

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your content script is loading before the whole document is loaded.That's why it returned `undefined`.
To make sure your content scripts are inject at properly, you should define "`run_at`" in file `manifest.json` 
Example:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
```

please check [Content Scripts parameters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for more details.

Comment: I added run_at and all_frames lines to manifest.json but i still get the same undefined.